# How to restrict access to routes in react-router?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

Does anyone know how to restrict access to particular routes in react-router? I want to check if the user is logged in before allowing access to a particular route. I thought it would be simple, but the docs aren't clear how to do it.

Is this something I should set up where I define my `<Route>` components, or should I be handling it inside my component handlers?

```
<Route handler={App} path="/">
  <NotFoundRoute handler={NotFound} name="not-found"/>
  <DefaultRoute handler={Login} name="login"/>
  <Route handler={Todos} name="todos"/> {/* I want this to be restricted */}
</Route>
```

Comment: If they aren't logged in, redirect to the login handler. Also note that the client has access to all of the JS it loads, so don't store sensitive info in it.

Comment: @Tanner Semerad do you have any github repository about how you achieved this briefly.

Comment: @jit I don't, sorry. The answer from miciek below was what I needed, but keep in mind that this was prior to react-router 1.0. I know a number of things have changed since 1.0 was released, but it's mostly similar.

Answer (score 122, accepted):

#### Update (Aug 16, 2019)

In react-router v4 and using React Hooks this looks a little different. Let's start with your `App.js`.

```js
export default function App() {
  const [isAuthenticated, userHasAuthenticated] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    onLoad();
  }, []);

  async function onLoad() {
    try {
      await Auth.currentSession();
      userHasAuthenticated(true);
    } catch (e) {
      alert(e);
    }
  }

  return (
    <div className="App container">
      <h1>Welcome to my app</h1>
      <Switch>
        <UnauthenticatedRoute
          path="/login"
          component={Login}
          appProps={{ isAuthenticated }}
        />
        <AuthenticatedRoute
          path="/todos"
          component={Todos}
          appProps={{ isAuthenticated }}
        />
        <Route component={NotFound} />
      </Switch>
    </div>
  );
}
```

We are using an `Auth` library to check if the user is currently authenticated. Replace this with your auth check function. If so then we set the `isAuthenticated` flag to `true`. We do this when our App first loads. Also worth mentioning, you might want to add a loading sign on your app while the auth check is being run, so you don't flash the login page every time you refresh the page.

Then we pass the flag to our routes. We create two type of routes `AuthenticatedRoute` and `UnauthenticatedRoute`.

The `AuthenticatedRoute.js` looks like this.

```js
export default function AuthenticatedRoute({ component: C, appProps, ...rest }) {
  return (
    <Route
      {...rest}
      render={props =>
        appProps.isAuthenticated
          ? <C {...props} {...appProps} />
          : <Redirect
              to={`/login?redirect=${props.location.pathname}${props.location.search}`}
            />}
    />
  );
}
```

It checks if `isAuthenticated` is set to `true`. If it is, then it'll render the desired component. If not, then it'll redirect to the login page.

The `UnauthenticatedRoute.js` on the other hand looks like this.

```js
export default ({ component: C, appProps, ...rest }) =>
  <Route
    {...rest}
    render={props =>
      !appProps.isAuthenticated
        ? <C {...props} {...appProps} />
        : <Redirect to="/" />}
  />;
```

In this case, if the `isAuthenticated` is set to `false`, it'll render the desired component. And if it is set to true, it'll send you to the homepage.

You can find detailed versions of this on our guide - https://serverless-stack.com/chapters/create-a-route-that-redirects.html.

#### Older version

The accepted answer is correct but Mixins are considered to be harmful (https://facebook.github.io/react/blog/2016/07/13/mixins-considered-harmful.html) by the React team.

If somebody comes across this question and is looking for the recommended way to do this, I'd suggest using Higher Order Components instead of Mixins.

Here is an example of a HOC that'll check if the user is logged in before proceeding. And if the user is not logged in, then it'll redirect you to the login page. This component takes a prop called `isLoggedIn`, that is basically a flag that your application can store to denote if the user is logged in.

```js
import React from 'react';
import { withRouter } from 'react-router';

export default function requireAuth(Component) {

  class AuthenticatedComponent extends React.Component {

    componentWillMount() {
      this.checkAuth();
    }

    checkAuth() {
      if ( ! this.props.isLoggedIn) {
        const location = this.props.location;
        const redirect = location.pathname + location.search;

        this.props.router.push(`/login?redirect=${redirect}`);
      }
    }

    render() {
      return this.props.isLoggedIn
        ? <Component { ...this.props } />
        : null;
    }

  }

  return withRouter(AuthenticatedComponent);
}
```

And to use this HOC, just wrap it around your routes. In case of your example, it would be:

```
<Route handler={requireAuth(Todos)} name="todos"/>
```

I cover this and a few other topics in a detailed step-by-step tutorial here - [https://serverless-stack.com/chapters/create-a-hoc-that-checks-auth.html](https://serverless-stack.com/chapters/create-a-route-that-redirects.html)

Comment: If my original code was using <Route getComponent={myAsyncComponentGenerator}>, how would I make it work with this example?

Comment: I have very similar code, but my question is, is is secured enough?
I mean may be an attacker can change the JS minified code such that replacing `this.props.isLoggedIn` with `true` and bypass login?

Comment: @karimelhelawy That is true and because of that you need to enforce authentication in your server's API.

Comment: `<Route handler={}/>` is deprecated in v1.0, you should use `<Route component={} />`.

Comment: `componentWillMount` are soon going to be deprecated. [Read it in the blog post on reactjs.org](https://reactjs.org/blog/2018/03/27/update-on-async-rendering.html). Instead I would go with the answer @jacob provided.

Comment: If you do it on `ComponentWillMount`, you are causing a side effect. I think the best place to call `checkAuth()` is on `ComponentDidMount`. Still, I think this answer is the best solution presented here. [React docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#unsafe_componentwillmount)

Comment: here is updated code
in html write 
<Route exact path="/exampleComponent"  component={requireAuth(ExampleComponent)}  />

in auth component write
this.props.history.push(`/login?redirect=${redirect}`);

Answer (score 42):

There is (now?) an example of this in React Router 4's docs for [`Redirect`](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/Redirect)

```
import { Route, Redirect } from 'react-router'

<Route exact path="/" render={() => (
  loggedIn ? (
    <Redirect to="/dashboard"/>
  ) : (
    <PublicHomePage/>
  )
)}/>
```

Comment: How can i use "loggedIn" as function or variable?. can you just explain it little bit

Comment: @KunvarSingh it should probably be a function because the value changes.

Comment: if `loggedIn` is async function this approach will not work

Answer (score 5):

`react-router` encourages a declarative approach for your router, you should make your router as dumb as possible and avoid putting your routing logic in your components.

Here is how you can do it (assuming you pass it the `loggedIn` prop):

```
const DumbRouter = ({ loggedIn }) => (
  <Router history={history}>
    <Switch>
      {[
        !loggedIn && LoggedOutRoutes,
        loggedIn && LoggedInRouter,
        <Route component={404Route} />
      ]}
    </Switch>
  </Router>
);

const LoggedInRoutes = [
  <Route path="/" component={Profile} />
];

const LoggedOutRoutes = [
  <Route path="/" component={Login} />
];
```

Comment: This is very simple, which is good. The thing is that you usually want to recognise the same routes either if you are logged out or in, so you can properly redirect to login if the user was logged out. You usually want routes to be the same, but to behave in a different way depending on the logged in status. Also with your solution you are adding duplication, by creating the same Route in 2 different locations whicih is harder to maintain.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to use authentication across your whole application, you need to store some data application-wide (e.g. token). You can set up two React mixins that are responsible for managing `$auth` object. This object shouldn't be available outside those two mixins. Here's example of that:

```
define('userManagement', function() {
    'use strict';

    var $auth = {
        isLoggedIn: function () {
            // return something, e.g. using server-stored data
        }
    };

    return {
        Authenticator: {
           login: function(username, password) {
               // modify $auth object, or call server, or both
           }
        },

        NeedsAuthenticatedUser: {
            statics: {
                willTransitionTo: function (transition) {
                    if (!$auth.isLoggedIn()) {
                        transition.abort();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    };
});
```

Then you can just mixin `Authenticator` mixing to your login components (login screen, login popup, etc) and call `this.login` function when you have all the data necessary.

The most important thing is protecting your components by mixing in `NeedsAuthenticatedUser` mixin. Each component that needs authenticated user will have to look like that:

```
var um = require('userManagement');

var ProtectedComponent = React.createClass({
    mixins: [um.NeedsAuthenticatedUser]
    // ...
}
```

Note that `NeedsAuthenticatedUser` uses react-router API (`willTransitionTo` and `transition.abort()`).

Comment: Mixins are bad idea to move on. [Read more](https://medium.com/@dan_abramov/mixins-are-dead-long-live-higher-order-components-94a0d2f9e750#.egtnavn6d)

Comment: A much better way which I found : https://github.com/reactjs/react-router/tree/master/examples/auth-flow

Comment: Mixins have been removed form ES6 and React has been deprecating them.

Answer (score 2):

You can use HOC and auth is a variable you can change value true or false means(authorization)

```
<Route path="/login" component={SignIn} />
<Route path="/posts" render = {() => (auth ?  (<Post />) : (<Redirect to="/login" />))}/>
```

Answer (score 1):

*private-route.tsx*

```
import {Redirect, Route, RouteProps} from 'react-router';
import * as React from 'react';

interface PrivateRouteProps extends RouteProps {
  /**
   * '/login' for example.
   */
  redirectTo: string;

  /**
   * If true, won't redirect.
   * We are using a function instead of a bool, a bool does not seem to be updated
   * after having successfully authenticated.
   */
  isLogged: () => boolean;
}


export function PrivateRoute(props: PrivateRouteProps) {
  // `component: Component` is not typing, it assign the value to a new variable.
  let { isLogged, redirectTo, component: Component, ...rest }: any = props;

  // error: JSX type element Component does not have call signature or ... AVOIDED BY ADDING ANY, still work,
  // and did not find a proper way to fix it.
  return <Route {...rest} render={(props) => (
    isLogged()
      ? <Component {...props}/>
      : <Redirect to={{
        pathname: redirectTo,
        state: { from: props.location }
      }} />
  )} />;
}
```

Usage:

```
        <PrivateRoute exact={true} 
                      path="/admin/" 
                      redirectTo={'/admin/login'} 
                      isLogged={this.loginService.isLogged} 
                      component={AdminDashboardPage}/>
        <Route path="/admin/login/" component={AdminLoginPage}/>
```

Based on https://tylermcginnis.com/react-router-protected-routes-authentication/.

Answer (score 0):

You can avoid to render component before confirming authentication, like as below:

```
import { useState, useEffect, useRef } from 'react';
import { useHistory } from 'react-router-dom';

const Route = () => {
    const [loading, sertLoading] = useState(true);
    const history = useHistory();

    const ref = useRef<Function>({});

    // must use ref!
    ref.current.routeGuard = () => {
        const authenticationHandler = (): boolean => {
         // do authentication here
        }
        sertLoading(true);
        const go = authenticationHandler();
        if (go === false) {
            history.goBack();
        }
        sertLoading(false);
    } 

    useEffect(() => {
        ref.current.routeGuard();
        history.listen(() => {
            ref.current.routeGuard();
        });
    }, []);

    return (
        <>
            {!loading && <YourRouteComponent />}
        </>
    )
};
```

Or simply, `yarn add react-routers`, which component have props `beforeEach`, `beforeRoute` like Vue Route.

Answer (score -2):

usually a logged in user will be granted a token, and uses this token for any communication with server. What we usually do is define a root page, and things build on top of that page. this root page does localisation, authentication and other configurations for you.

here's an example

```
Routes = (
    <Route path="/" handler={Root}>
        <Route name="login" handler={Login} />
        <Route name="forget" handler={ForgetPassword} />
        <Route handler={Main} >
            <Route name="overview" handler={Overview} />
            <Route name="profile" handler={Profile} />
            <DefaultRoute handler={Overview} />
        </Route>
        <DefaultRoute handler={Login} />
        <NotFoundRoute handler={NotFound} />
    </Route>
);
```

on your root page, check for token null or authenticate the token with server to see if user is valid login.

hope this helps :)

Comment: Right, so how would I stop the "Overview" class to be imported if Auth hasn't gone through, or what does the "Main" handler look like? For instance, what if "Overview" has a dependency that requires an authenticated app to run? Because it is imported to run on the router, all its dependencies will have been imported too, and thus you have a broken app right?

Comment: This does not answer the question that was asked